# How to block FIN-WAIT-2 by iptables?

Tags: iptables, ddos

My site now is under ddos-attack,
"ss -ant" shows a lot of **FIN-WAIT-2** (and some **FIN-WAIT-1**) connections from one ip (and random ports), about 500-700 connections:

```
FIN-WAIT-2 0      0         ::ffff:MY_IP:443                 ::ffff:ATTACKERS_IP:RANDOM_PORT   
.... 500-700 times
```

Im trying to use

```
iptables -A INPUT -s ATTACKERS_IP -j DROP
```

and

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,RST RST -m limit --limit 1/s -j ACCEPT
```

and

```
echo "2" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout
```

but it doesnt help - new connections are coming in with another random ports.

So, how to TOTALLY block specific IP by iptables (or maybe something else) to prevent FIN-WAIT-2 flood by ip which freezes the server?

Answer (score 0):

It depends, there's a ton of ways to approach the problem.  You could block the whole country if it's a foreign-language country (provided your website is not of international market or interest).
or
You could block an entire ip block
or
You could use cloudflare to pre-mitigate the problem
or
You could ....